# Como alterar web.config ao executar o Deploy?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

Tenho um ambiente de homologação e outro de produção na nuvem mas efetuo o *Deploy* em *File System*.

Tenho que inserir alguns parâmetros e alterar a *connectionString* para cada um desses ambientes.

**Exemplos de parâmetros:**

- Informação para saber quando é ambiente de homologação e nesse não enviar e-mails para clientes, somente para as caixas de entrada de teste;
- Informar o diretório onde os arquivos deverão ser salvos.

Existe alguma forma de mudar o **web.config**, acrescentando ou alteração parâmetros dependendo da opção de *Deploy* que eu escolher?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar o [Web.Release.config](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd465318(v=vs.100).aspx) onde as alterações podem ser feitas no momento da publicação.

No link acima ele tem um exemplo de como funciona, vale uma lida, é bem legal.

Um exemplo pratico dele que eu uso que é para subir um servidor apenas em produção é assim:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="RodaServ" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" value="true"/>
```

Onde ele muda a key `RodaServ` para `true` quando é publicado.

Comment: +1 @Ricardo, obrigado pela dica. Mas para os dois eu preciso efetuar o Deploy em padrão Release.

Comment: Vê se o segundo parágrafo do passo 2 no link te atenderia, fiquei meio sem entender o que exatamente você quer fazer, talvez o que ele fala lá ajude.

Comment: Sou péssimo em inglês (aliás, não tenho inglês), mas se essa página estivesse em inglês seria melhor do que essa tradução (rs). Mas segui os passos. Adicionei uma nova ***Solution Configuration*** em ***Solution Manager*** e dei o nome de **Homologacao**. Cliquei com o direito em cima do ***web.Config*** e cliquei em ***Add Config Transform*** e então foi criado o ***web.homologacao.config***. Depois foi só adicionar uma nova configuração de Deploy selecionando essa nova configuração. Adicionei seu exemplo de alteração de parâmetro e funcionou. Muitíssimo obrigado!!